# Why Can't Mathematica Integrate this?

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration, calculus-and-analysis

I have the following problem from a textbook I am trying to integrate:

[image]

So, following the directions in text, I am required to integrate each function. However, I cannot get Mathematica to integrate the first function. Here is my code:

```
Z1 := E^-x^2*Cos[x^2 + y^2]
Z2 := 2 - x^2 - y^2
Plot3D[{Z1, Z2}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, AspectRatio -> 1, ViewPoint -> {4, 1, 1}]
Integrate[Z2, {y, -1, 1}, {x, -1, 1}] - Integrate[Z1, {y, -1, 1}, {x, -1, 1}]
```

They plot OK:

[image]

but give me really strange output:

[image]

Could someone please explain how I can overcome this? Wolfram|Alpha can [evaluate it](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5BE%5E-x%5E2*Cos%5Bx%5E2%20%2b%20y%5E2%5D,%20%7By,%20-1,%201%7D,%20%7Bx,%20-1,%201%7D%5D) without (much) trouble.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Mathematica* is giving you an exact symbolic result. If want a numeric integral, you should use `NIntegrate` instead of `Integrate`, or just wrap your result in `N`. If you want, say, 30 significant digits,

```
N[Integrate[Z2, {y, -1, 1}, {x, -1, 1}] - 
  Integrate[Z1, {y, -1, 1}, {x, -1, 1}], 30]
```

> 3.02706907398351331410210839012 + 0.*10^-31 I

Comment: Yep, that was it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use, in principle, `Boole` inside `Integrate` like this:

```
NIntegrate[
 Boole[E^-x^2 Cos[x^2 + y^2] < z < 2 - x^2 - y^2], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1,
   1}, {z, -1, 3}]
```

the result is given as 3.0138472, despite warnings `NIntegrate::slwcon:` and `NIntegrate::eincr:`

I'm not able to figure out what actually happens at present, but I'm sure this way of using `Boole` will helps, especially for the integration of irregular regions or volumes.