# How to plot and find the volume of a solid?

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis

How to plot and find the volume of the solid enclosed between the paraboloid `z=5(x^2+y^2)` and `z=6-7x^2-y^2`

And the answer of the volume is `3Pi/(2)^1/2`

Comment: A few related questions: [15010](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15010/why-cant-mathematica-integrate-this), [18743](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18743/calculating-volume), [27645](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27645/calculating-volume-between-two-surfaces-of-revolution), [37671](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37671/volume-within-parameter-space)

Answer (score 17):

```
RegionPlot3D[ 5 (x^2 + y^2) < z < 6 - 7 x^2 - y^2, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -0, 6}, 
             PlotStyle -> Orange, Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Integrate[ Boole[5 (x^2 + y^2) < z < 6 - 7 x^2 - y^2], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, 0, 6}]
(*
 (3 π)/Sqrt[2]
*)
```

Comment: +1, beautiful - just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 17):

```
Plot3D[{5 (x^2 + y^2), 6 - 7 x^2 - y^2}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
        RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, 5 (x^2 + y^2) < 6 - 7 x^2 - y^2]]
```

[image]

```
Integrate[(6 - 7 x^2 - y^2 - 5 (x^2 + y^2)) UnitStep[(6 - 7 x^2 - y^2 - 5 (x^2 + y^2))],
          {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}]
```

> ```
> (3 π)/Sqrt[2]
> ```

**Edit**

Since working with the `UnitStep` function (rather unexpectedly) doesn't appear the most efficient approach we provide here a bit different but more obvious way exploiting `HeavisideTheta`.

```
Defer @ 
Integrate[(6 - 7 x^2 - y^2 - 5 (x^2 + y^2)) HeavisideTheta[(6 - 7 x^2 - y^2 - 5 (x^2 + y^2))],
          {x, -∞, ∞}, {y, -∞, ∞}] == 
Integrate[# HeavisideTheta[#] &[(6 - 7 x^2 - y^2 - 5 (x^2 + y^2))],
          {x, -∞, ∞}, {y, -∞, ∞}] // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

This is a faster and more elegant way than belisarius' approach in *Mathematica 8* and *9*

```
Integrate[ Boole[5 (x^2 + y^2) < z < 6 - 7 x^2 - y^2], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, 0, 6}]//
AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> ```
> 2.228000
> ```

```
Integrate[ # HeavisideTheta[#] &[(6 - 7 x^2 - y^2 - 5 (x^2 + y^2))], 
          {x, -∞, ∞}, {y, -∞, ∞}] // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> ```
> 0.245000
> ```

**Warning:** In *Mathematica 7* there was a bug and the `HeavisideTheta` approach yielded an incorrect result, therefore we had to deal with `UnitStep` or `Boole` approaches.

Comment: +1 for the plot.  Belisarius's `Integrate` code appears cleaner and faster however.  (If I'm wrong tell me.)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Now I provided cleaner and faster solution, unfortunately you won't be able to verify it if you still work with `Mathematica 7` only.

Comment: Touché. :-) . .

Answer (score 10):

The projection of your solid down to the $xy$-plane is described by
$$5(x^2+y^2) \leq 6-7x^2-y^2,$$
which simplifies to
$$12x^2+6y^2 \leq 6.$$
This is an equation of a solid ellipse $E$ compressed by the factor $\sqrt{2}$ in the $x$-direction. The volume can be expressed as
$$\iint\limits_E (6-(12x^2+6y^2)) \, dA.$$

A truly efficient way to evaluate this integral is to work in an elliptic coordinate system: 
$$x=r\cos(t)/\sqrt{2}, \; y=r\sin(t).$$ In this coordinate system, the function simplifies to $6-6r^2$ and the area element is $dA=(r/\sqrt{2})\, dr \, dt$. The area element is similar to the familiar $dA = r\,dr\,d\theta$ in polar coordinates, but accounts for the extra compression in the $x$-direction. The formula can also be derived using the [Jacobian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant).

Using this coordinate system, the integral can now be expressed as
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 (6-6r^2)r/\sqrt{2} \, dr\, dt = 3\pi/\sqrt{2},$$
which is quite easy to do by hand.

We can also use this point of view to make a nice image:

```
With[{x = r*Cos[t]/Sqrt[2], y = r*Sin[t]},
  solid = ParametricPlot3D[{
     {x, y, 5 (x^2 + y^2)},
     {x, y, (6 - 7 x^2 - y^2)}
     }, {r, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 2 Pi},
    PlotStyle -> {Directive[Lighter[Blue]], Directive[Orange]}];
  shell = ParametricPlot3D[{
     {x, y, 5 (x^2 + y^2)},
     {x, y, (6 - 7 x^2 - y^2)}
     }, {r, 1, 2}, {t, 0, 2 Pi},
    Mesh -> None,
    PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.4]];
  border = ParametricPlot3D[
    {Cos[t]/Sqrt[2], Sin[t], 5 (Cos[t]^2/2 + Sin[t]^2)},
    {t, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black]]
  ];
Show[{solid, shell, border}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {-0.2, 6.2}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I guess this is too old school.

```
Solve[ 5 (x^2 + y^2) == 6 - 7 x^2 - y^2, x]

{{x -> -(Sqrt[1 - y^2]/Sqrt[2])}, {x -> Sqrt[1 - y^2]/Sqrt[2]}}

Integrate[(6 - 7 x^2 - y^2) - 5 (x^2 + y^2)  ,
         {y, -1, 1},
         {x, -(Sqrt[1 - y^2]/Sqrt[2]), Sqrt[1 - y^2]/Sqrt[2]}]

(3  π)/Sqrt[2]
```

Thsn again if you need to show your work on your calculus homework this is how you do it.