# Plot3D region bounded by equations?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I have four equations, $$ z = xy \\ z=0 \\ y=x^2 \\ x=y^2$$ I would like to integrate the region bounded by them.

Before this, I would like to plot the region they bound, but I cannot seem to find any documentation on how to do this with `Plot3D` or `RegionPlot3D`

Comment: Try `ContourPlot3D`.

Comment: These surfaces partition space into several segments.  To select the one you need, you must rewrite them as *inequalities*, not as equations.  Then it's trivial to plot the region using `RegionPlot3D`.

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of [(39161)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/39161/17)?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Maybe a duplicate, but I don't think it is unclear. In this case it seems there is one region bounded (with finite volume) by those surfaces. I mean, region bouded by  `x^2+y^2=1` is a sphere, while `x^2+y^2<=1` **is** a sphere.

Comment: @Kuba Most people seemed to feel that it was ambiguous, and I tended to agree.  Since you disagree please vote to reopen.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard You are right :P

Comment: @Kuba I suppose what people mean by "unclear" is that `=` doesn't indicate if he wants the region "inside" or "outside" (or left/right, above/below, etc.). To use your example, does `x^2 + y^2 =1` imply the solid sphere with radius 1 or the entire space except that sphere? :) Since the OP seems to have accepted your answer, please edit the question to fit the best possible interpretation and I'll gladly add a reopen vote :)

Comment: @rm-rf Yes `=` doesn't but with: "I would like to integrate the region bounded by them." it is clear we are talking about finite volume :). It is not obvious such region exists but OP does not share this concern with me. And existance or finding those regions are separate questions. That's why I have nothing to edit :/.

Comment: @Kuba I haven't tried it out myself, but I thought halirutan's answer was showing that there are many regions bounded by these equations... is that not the case?

Comment: @rm-rf I have not checked it very carefully but I think there is only one, others are bouded by plot region.

Comment: @Kuba OK, I've reopened it :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I dont know how to do this automatically, to find bouded region given with those surfaces. I guess ou could take each three and check if there is a finite intersection and then combine the result.

Meanwhile you can plot it as I've suggested and as Nasser has shown to get an idea what to loog for:

```
ContourPlot3D[{z==x y, z==0, y==x^2, x==y^2}, {x, #, #2}, {y, #3, #4}, {z, #5, #6},
    Mesh -> 1, ImageSize -> 500, BaseStyle -> 18, ViewPoint -> {5, 1, 2},
    ContourStyle -> (Directive @@@ {{Red}, {Green}, {Blue, Opacity@.3}, {Yellow}}),  
    Lighting -> "Neutral", AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}
] & @@@ {{-2, 2, -2, 2, -2, 2}, {0, 1, 0, 1, -.1, 1.1}} // Row
```

[image]

Ok, now we know:

```
RegionPlot3D[And @@ {z <= x y, z >= 0, y > x^2, x > y^2},
             {x, -.02, 1.1}, {y, -.02, 1.1}, {z, -.02, 1.02}, 
             Mesh -> 50, ImageSize -> 500, PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 10, 
             PlotStyle -> None]
```

[image]

Hard to get that `tip` in `{0,0,0}` :/. Ok, copy and paste first part of former code:

```
NIntegrate[ Boole[And @@ {z <= x y, z >= 0, y > x^2, x > y^2}], 
           {x, -.02, 1.1}, {y, -.02, 1.1}, {z, -.02, 1.02}]
```

> ```
> 0.0833333
> ```

Answer (score 5):

Your question, in its current form, is ambiguous and cannot be answered. Your equations don't bound a region, i.e. they only define surfaces. It is clear what you mean, but important information is missing.

If you want to use `RegionPlot3D`, you have to decide *which side* of the surface of each equation you consider to be *inside*. For your first equation, this could be $z\leq x y$ or $z\geq x y$. One way to find out which combination of inequalities you want is to make *all* combinations and look at them

```
eqs = {z == x y, z == 0, y == x^2, x == y^2};
With[{possibilities = (Apply @@@ Transpose[{#, eqs}]) & /@ 
    Tuples[{GreaterEqual, LessEqual}, 4]},
 RegionPlot3D[And @@ #, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -20, 20}, {z, -20, 20}] & /@
   possibilities
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

OK, since the rest is done in Kubas answer, I'll stop here and leave this as it is.