# Plotting multiple planes and calculating the volume of the area surrounded by the planes

Tags: plotting

I'm currently having trouble trying to plot multiple planes into *Mathematica*. The planes that I'm  supposed to plot are
x=0,
y=0,
x+y=1,
x+z=0 and
z=x^2+y^2.

I've noticed that I can't plot planes if the z-variable isn't there. I've tried using `Plot3D`, `ContourPlot3D` and `ParametricPlot3D` but I'm not having any success.

The second problem is trying to calculate the area that is enclosed by the planes themselves.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:
I managed to plot the graphs. Is there an easy way to integrate between the surfaces or some other way to find the volume that is being surrounded by the planes. Props to Kuba and Dr. belisarius by the way :)!

EDIT2:
Heres the code that i used to plot the equations.

```
ContourPlot3D[{x == 0, y == 0, x + y == 1, x + z == 0, z == x^2 + y^2}, {x, -5, 5}, 
  {y, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5}]
```

Comment: Works fine: `ContourPlot3D[x == 0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}]`.

Comment: `z=x^2+y^2.` is an uncommon plane

Comment: The problem is that I have to plot all of the planes on the same graph.

Comment: Take a look at: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/41183/plot3d-region-bounded-by-equations/41191#41191

Comment: Please add the code you used to plot the "planes"

Comment: ContourPlot3D[{x == 0, y == 0, x + y == 1, x + z == 0, 
  z == x^2 + y^2}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5}]

Comment: The answer to your edit is in the linked topic. Keep in mind that it is not clear at all which part of space you want to measure.

Comment: Yes I can see that. Im not sure either. I was just given a problem to plot the functions and then calculate the volume that is bounded by them. The topic that you linked didn't really help me with the integration part. I assumed there would be a way to just get the bounded piece with a code like RegionPlot3D and then get the volume of it. Im pretty confused at the moment.