# Volume under a List3dPlot?

Tags: graphics3d

Is there a way to find the volume in cubic feet under a ListPlot3D mesh, in positive and negative regions? I have tried using the Volume command.  I created a 3D plot from an excel file of x,y, and z values.

Comment: You could compute the volume by summing over "infinitesimal" volumes. Otherwise, [39161](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39161/how-to-plot-and-find-the-volume-of-a-solid) and related questions might be helpful even if they do not provide a direct answer.

Comment: What is your definition of volume for a set of points in 3D space?

Comment: The volume would be enclosed by the x,y plane and the boundary of the points in space connected together to form a mesh.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know what you mean by "in positive and negative regions," but here's a way if the function is nonnegative.

```
SeedRandom[0]; (* for reproducible results *)
data = Table[{x = RandomReal[{0, 1}], y = RandomReal[{0, 1}], 1 - x^2 + y^2}, {300}];
plot = ListPlot3D[data, BoxRatios -> Automatic, Filling -> 0]
reg = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics@Show@DiscretizeGraphics@plot
Volume@reg
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
(*  0.951312   <-- volume *)
```

Note: `DiscretizeGraphics@plot` produces a surface (dimension 2) that has no volume. `Show` converts the region to a `Graphics3D` object consisting of polygons that happen to form a polyhedron. `BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics` converts the graphics to the solid region contained by the polyhedron.  Roundabout, but I didn't find a more direct way.

If "negative regions" means the function might be negative, then you have to chose a lower bound for what space is to be considered under the graph.  For instance, the above problem translated down by 1:

```
SeedRandom[0];
data = Table[{x = RandomReal[{0, 1}], y = RandomReal[{0, 1}], -x^2 + y^2}, {300}];
plot = ListPlot3D[data, BoxRatios -> Automatic, Mesh -> None, 
   PlotRange -> {-1, 1}, Filling -> -1];
reg = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics@Show@DiscretizeGraphics@plot;
Volume@reg
(*  0.951312  *)
```

It is important that the plot range contain the whole region (or parts will be lopped off and the internal meshing function that discretizes the graphics will complain).

Comment: But where does my x,y,z data get input?  I am trying to attach a screenshot but can't figure out how right now...  Thank you very much for the answer.

Comment: It worked perfectly, thanks again for the answer.