# Volumize interpolated ListPlot3D

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I have a large list of data points `(x,y,z)`. I have plotted them using `ListPlot3D` and then i generated a smooth surface covering the points using `InterpolationOrder->3`. Now i need to find the volume fraction under this smooth surface. How can i do this, so the processing is fast.

I have tried `BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics@Show@DiscretizeGraphics` ([Volume under a List3dPlot?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/162532/volume-under-a-list3dplot)) but the evaluation does not complete even after a couple of hours. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If the x,y coordinates form a grid consider using Interpolation and NIntegrate. I'm not sure visualizing something is the best way to integrate it.

Comment: It would help, if you would provide more detailes about what you have already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data points lie on a regular grid, right? Than you can apply the trapezoidal rule directly to the data set:

First, I have to generate a fictive data set: `pts` are the coordinates in the plane and `z` denotes the elevation of the surface (yes, I presume that your surface is actually a graph).

```
xmin = 0.; xmax = 1.; xn = 1000;
ymin = 0.; ymax = 1.; yn = 1000;
pts = Tuples[{Subdivide[xmin, xmax, xn], Subdivide[ymin, ymax, yn]}];
f = {x, y} \[Function] x^2 x Sin[5 x + 3 y] + 1/2 Sin[7 x + 13 Pi y];
z = f @@ Transpose[pts];
```

This computes the integral with the two-dimensional trapezoidal rule (utilizing the fact that the data lies on a tensor product grid). If your surface is of class $C^2$, then the error should be proportional to the square of the diagional of the grid quadrilaterals.

```
xω = ConstantArray[1., xn + 1]; xω[[1]] = 0.5; 
xω[[-1]] = 0.5;
yω = ConstantArray[1., yn + 1]; yω[[1]] = 0.5; 
yω[[-1]] = 0.5;
int1 = (xmax - xmin)/xn (ymax - ymin)/yn (yω.Partition[z, xn + 1].xω);
```

> -0.0742535

For checking the accuracy, here is the same integral computed with `NIntegrate`:

```
int2 = NIntegrate[ f[x, y], {x, xmin, xmax}, {y, xmin, xmax}, AccuracyGoal -> 10, Method -> "GaussKronrodRule" ]
```

> -0.0742538

There is definitely some error, but for inaccurate input data, this is really negligble:

```
Abs[int1 - int2]/Abs[int2]
```

> 3.96486*10^-6

## General hint

Make sure that your data `z = data[[All,3]]` is a packed array of machine precision numbers, for example with `` z = Deverloper`ToPackedArray[data[[All,3]]] ``.

Comment: Thank you this helped with the problem. But i managed to use a completely different method to solve this problem

Comment: You're welcome. If you found an approach that suited your needs even better, why not sharing it with the community and self-answer your question?

Comment: i just needed the volume fraction, so i summed all the z-values in relation to the grid ( since the x and y values are similar to that of the grid). So i didn't have to perform a complex integration.